# Web service no aparece en Netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, webservice, netbeans-8.2

queria saber a que dse debe que no aparece la opcion web service client en netbeans 8.2, selecciono new-->others y no esta, ya bsque en el find y nada, no encuentro mucha ayuda en google. Por favor, alguien me ayuda? de ante mano muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

De seguro que debes tener solo Java SE y no el Java EE.

Revisa si te aparece la opción de crear sitios web con JSP O SERVLET, si no te aparece te falta instalar Java EE